# Extracting text between <p> tags, jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, parsing, jsoup

Given this HTML:

```
<html> 
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <p>
        "Text"
        <br>
        "Some more Text"
        <br> 
        "Even more text"
        </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get the text inside the `<p>` tags with §Element description = document.select(______)`. How can I get this text? I was able to do it with a page that didn't have a body but I'm not sure how to get past the body tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can use the selector: `p` to extract all `<p>` elements and use the element accessor: `text()` to read the text from within each `<p>` element.

Here's an example using the HTML provided in your question:

```
@Test
public void canGetTextFromAPElement() {
    String html = "<html> \n" +
            "   <head></head>\n" +
            "   <body>\n" +
            "      <p>\n" +
            "        \"Text\"\n" +
            "        <br>\n" +
            "        \"Some more Text\"\n" +
            "        <br> \n" +
            "        \"Even more text\"\n" +
            "        </p>\n" +
            "  </body>\n" +
            "</html>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Elements elements = doc.select("p");

    assertThat(elements.size(), is(1));
    assertThat(elements.get(0).text(), is("\"Text\" \"Some more Text\" \"Even more text\""));
}
```